# How to fill out table data contents on auto sized table?

Tags: css, xhtml

Currently I'm working on two table columns next to eachother, which contents must be of equal height. Sounds classic, however, the table/row/cells can't be given a fixed height, because it will be different every time.

I've simplified the case to this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>Test</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /></head>
<body>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 500px; border: 2px solid blue;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%;"><div style="height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />left</div></td>
        <td style="height: 100%;"><div style="margin-left: 20px; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">right</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So I'd like the yellow blocks to be of equal height, without giving table/row/cell/div a fixed width (relative is fine). I know the table cells can be given a yellow background, but this is a simplified example of blocks that can me minimized, moved, etc., so giving table cells a color is not an option. Use of tables is not necessary, but thought it would be better to illustrate this case.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem exactly but - you are giving a height of 100% to the div and it's parent also has 100% - but obviously this won't work since the div and also td has no relative from which to calculate those 100%.

As a solution you could try doing it with faux columns. A list apart has a nice article about it http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/ .

Comment: Allright, I understand the td has no relative from which to calculate. Was hoping that 100% also represented the space it has at 'runtime'. Unfortunately.

For this specific case faux columns are not an option unfortunately. I guess it will be down to javascript/jquery to obtain equal height to both columns.